# Was bedeuten die Wörter 'ne und 'n?

Tags: meaning

Ich habe in einem Buch diese Sätze gesehen.

> Hier ham sich die Bergleute gewaschen und sich umgezogen, 'ne dunkle Baumwolljacke und 'ne Hose, und dann bekam jeder noch'n Helm. Für die Sicherheit. Die sahen dann nachher alle so aus wie ich jetz für die Touristen.
>   Heutzutage is dat nun 'n Raum für Tanzveranstaltungen.

Was bedeuten die Wörter 'ne und 'n im Satz?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 'n = ein
>
> 'ne = eine

Das "ei" wurde weg reduziert. Es spricht sich damit schneller.

Answer (score 3):

Das sind Artikel. Auf Deutsch: »Geschlechtswörter«. Aber den deutschen Namen verwendet man selten.

Der zitierte Text ist eine Wiedergabe von gesprochener Umgangssprache aus einer eher nördlichen Region Deutschlands, also kein Standarddeutsch. Daher sind viele Wörter verschliffen und verkürzt. Es sind auch nicht alle Sätze vollständig.

Standarddeutsch würde dieser Text wie folgt lauten:

> Hier haben sich die Bergleute gewaschen und sich umgezogen, *[jeder hat]* eine dunkle Baumwolljacke und eine Hose *[angezogen]*, und dann bekam jeder noch einen Helm. *[Den bekam er]* für die Sicherheit. Die sahen dann nachher alle so aus wie ich jetzt für die Touristen.
>   Heutzutage ist das nun ein Raum für Tanzveranstaltungen.

Comment: Aus der Frage ist nicht ersichtlich, ob es um *'ne* an sich oder den Unterschied zwischen *eine* und *'ne* geht. Eventuell könnte auch Begriffe wie **Reduktionsform**, **Kurzform** oder **Klitikon** gesucht sein.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Was hindert dich daran, das in einer Antwort zu schreiben?

Comment: "Geschlechtswörter" habe ich nun wirklich noch nie gehört. Ich kenne nur Tunwörter und Sachwörter.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn ich mich richtig entsinne, ist das deutsche Wort, dass vermehrt - vor allem im frühen Lernstadium (etwa 1./2. Klasse im Deutschunterricht) - verwendet wird, *der Begleiter*. Danach ist man langsam von den dt. vereinfachten Begriffen (auch Tunwort, Wiewort) zu den lat. Fachbegriffen übergegangen. Die meisten Wortarten besitzen auch traditionelle deutsche Begriffe, die aber zumeist übergangen werden (wie etwa hier Geschlechtswort oder Bei-/Eigenschaftswort)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Erster Satz aus [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artikel_(Wortart)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artikel_(Wortart)): »Ein Artikel (von lateinisch articulus, deutsch ‚Gelenk‘; in der traditionellen deutschen Grammatik auch **Geschlechtswort** oder Begleiter) ist ein grammatisches Wort, das regelmäßig ein Substantiv (einschließlich Substantivierungen) begleitet.«

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann 'Geschlechtswort' kannte ich noch aus irgendwelchen Lang-ist's-her-'Sprachbüchern'. 'Tunwort' kannte ich bis jetzt nur als 'Tuwort'. Von dem Gebrauch dieser pseudo-erklärenden deutschen Bezeichnungen würde ich abraten. Ich habe schon Schwierigkeiten genug, Deutschlernern zu erklären, dass 'sein' ein Verb ist - ihnen zu erklären, dass es ein 'Tu(n)wort' (Tätigkeitsbezeichner) ist, würde sie vollends verwirren. Das gilt auch für 'wohnen', 'liegen', 'bleiben' usw.

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Ich habe als Kind für Verben den Begriff »Zeitwort« gelernt, habe aber vor wenigen Jahren erfahren, dass dieser Begriff in Deutschland nur selten verwendet wird, und offenbar sogar Muttersprachler verwirrt. In österreichischen Volksschulen (entspricht den deutschen Grundschulen) ist dieser Begriff aber auch heute noch die Standardbezeichnung für Verben: https://www.mein-lernen.at/vs-deutsch/zeitwort

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Diese österreichische Lösung finde ich besser als 'Tu(n)wort', aber auch sie ist nicht makellos: Die Partizipien sind irgendwo auch temporal markiert, als Präsens' und 'Perfekt' und so gesehen auch 'Zeitwörter'. Optimal für meine Zwecke wäre eine Bezeichnung, die ausdrückt, dass diese Wörter (Verben) in sechs 'Personen' auftreten können, das können alle anderen Wortarten nicht. Auch hier gibt's Ausnahmen (*ich regne), die aber nicht das Prinzip außer Kraft setzen.

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Der Prinz mit dem roten Schal setzte sich in sein Schlauchboot und flog damit in den Himmel. Dort traf er eine große weiche weiße Schäfchenwolke, die gerade aussah wie ein Turnschuh. »Wer bist du?« fragte der Prinz mit dem roten Schal die Turnschuh-Wolke. »Ich bin eine Wolke« sagte die Wolke. »Und was machst du den ganzen Tag?« »Ich ziehe über den Himmel und ändere meine Form wenn ich fröhlich bin, und **ich regne** wenn ich traurig bin.«

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast  : )